# Unable to Import tensorflow.js in jupyter notebook(SyntaxError: Unexpected token import)

Tags: javascript, python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, tensorflow.js

Kindly look at the below screenshot:
[image]

I am trying to import tensorflow.js from javascript kernel of jupyter notebook.The image shows how I installed the module via terminal and how I am importing it and what's the error.
How to resolve it considering I am a newbie to javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `import` keyword was only introduced in ES6 (ECMAScript 6), so it's likely that you're using an older version. Update Node and see how you go.

Comment: Update 'Node' means Nodejs?I am noob , kindly elaborate

Comment: Yeah, I'm referring to updating NodeJS. Your version of ECMAScript doesn't support the `import` keyword. So you can upgrade NodeJS to get to the latest version, or as you've discovered, use the older `require` function.

Answer (score 0):

The Solution to import:

```
var tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs');
```